# Is it okay to do power off stalls in the clean configuration for a check ride?

Tags: stall, checkride

I’ve been renting a plane for a while and the owner has asked due to a safety concern that we don’t use flaps in our stalls or slow flight.

The airplane flying handbook and the ACS call for these to be done in the landing configuration. Would a DPE be okay with doing these maneuvers in a clean configuration given that is how we have been asked to fly the plane?

Comment: The owner might be saying "do not *move* them *during* stalls or slow flight" for the same reason they are not moved near the ground:  one might move and one does not, creating a serious aerodynamic imbalance.  One might ask for a clarification, and bring your instructor with you.  Flaps can be set *before* any of these manuevers.

Comment: I **always** do stalls when flying a new type. At sufficient altitude, of course. Not doing them robs you of the experience when you might come in slow to a landing and an unfortunate gust brings you below stall speed. Even with the usual precautions like flying the approach 10 knots above the usual speed in gusty weather cannot rule out such an event completely.

Doing them only in the clean configuration is not enough. The stall characteristics might differ **a lot** between the clean and landing configurations. But doing them clean **as well** is sensible.

Comment: That would ring alarm bells with me, and I would get to the bottom of it before I fly that airplane again. Is there a maintenance issue? Something the owner hasn't fixed? If it's because the owner is worried about accidents, it's practicing the recognition of approach to stalls and stall recovery that prevents accidents.

Comment: Many readers will be curious to know, what safety issue could have led to this request?  Seems odd.

Answer (score 2):

From the ACS for power-off stalls:

> PA.VII.B.S3 Configure the airplane in the approach or landing configuration, as specified by the evaluator, and maintain coordinated flight throughout the maneuver.

Unless you are in an aircraft that uses zero flaps in the approach configuration, then a power-off stall requires flaps per the ACS. This doesn't preclude practicing power-off stalls without flaps, but that's not a maneuver you'll be tested on.

I suggest you clarify with the aircraft owner. It doesn't make sense not to do slow flight and stalls in the approach and landing configuration. It's much safer to experience the slow flight edge of the envelope at safe altitude than to only be exposed to it when close to the ground!